# Set Theory: Simplify ((A∩(B∪C))∩(A−B))∩(B∪Cc)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to simplify this expression:

$((A\cap(B\cup C))\cap(A−B))\cap(B\cup C^c)$

With venn diagrams I am able to figure out that I should be able to simplify it down to an empty set. But I am getting stuck trying to write a proper proof for it. I have gotten this so far:

$((A\cap(B\cup C))\cap(A−B))\cap(B\cup C^c)$

$((A\cap(B\cup C))\cap(A\cap B^c))\cap(B\cup C^c)$ Set Difference Law

$(((A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C))\cap(A\cap B^c))\cap(B\cup C^c)$ Distributive law

what are the next steps?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! First take a look at the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can learn how to properly typeset these expressions.  I just edited it for you so you can also edit and take a look for how I did this.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a small, but very significant error in your application of the distributive law:

You've written $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$, but the distributive law says $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

So all together you now have:

$$[(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)] \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C)$$

**Edit to explain the empty set:**

We can now apply the distributive property again to get:

$$\left[(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C)\right] \cup \left[(A \cap C) \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C)\right]$$

Note that if $x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C)$, then $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \in A \cap B^C$, so in particular $x \in B$ and $x \in B^C$. No such $x$ exists! Thus $(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C) = \emptyset$. Similarly, $(A \cap C) \cap (A \cap B^C) \cap (A \cap C^C) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Good eyes! Nice answer.

Comment: thanks for spotting my mistake, I should have caught that. I can see why it's an empty set but I am having trouble going through the required steps to prove that it is one

Comment: @MattHale I've updated my answer for those final steps - is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

> I have gotten this so far:
>
> $((A\cap(B\cup C))\cap(A−B))\cap(B\cup C^c)$
>
> $((A\cap(B\cup C))\cap(A\cap B^c))\cap(B\cup C^c)$ Set Difference Law
>
> $\require{cancel}\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{(((A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C))\cap(A\cap B^c))\cap(B\cup C^c)}}}$ Distributive law

$\quad(((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))\cap(A\cap B^\mathsf c))\cap(B\cup C^\mathsf c)$ Distributive law

But *instead* of that, I would suggest distributing out the common conjunct.

$\quad (A\cap ((B\cup C)\cap B^\mathsf c))\cap(B\cup C^\mathsf c)$ Distributive law

$\quad A\cap (C\cap B^\mathsf c)\cap(B\cup C^\mathsf c)$ Absortion

The way forward should be clear from here.